# select max null values

Tags: sql, count, null, max

I need to select a property owner who owns the most number of properties that have not been viewed by prospective buyers.

What is the best way to select the 'propertyforrent.ownerno' where their number of 'propertyno IS NULL' is the highest.

THIS:

```
SELECT PropertyForRent.ownerno
FROM PropertyForRent propertyforrent, Client client, Viewing viewing
WHERE client.preftype=propertyforrent.type
AND client.clientno=viewing.clientno
AND viewing.propertyno IS NULL
ORDER BY count(*)
LIMIT 1
```

OR THIS:

```
SELECT PropertyForRent.ownerno
FROM PropertyForRent propertyforrent, Client client, Viewing viewing
WHERE client.preftype=propertyforrent.type
AND client.clientno=viewing.clientno
AND MAX(COUNT(viewing.propertyno IS NULL)
```

THANKS!!

Comment: Please not that in SQL `NULL` has special treatment.  `NULL` is **not** equal to any value, including another `NULL`.  You need to use `IS NULL` in your queries.

Comment: Meaning instead of of saying '='NULL'' I have to say 'IS NULL' right?

Comment: Yes. You got it. BTW, there's also `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: You cannot use multiple `WHERE` causes in the same query.

Comment: Thanks....would you have any suggestion as to how to select the 'owner.no' with the highest number of NULL values?

Comment: Both your queries does not make any sense, since you use `COUNT` without `GROUP BY` and apparently expect multiple values in the result.

Comment: thanks.....I added that in here and overlooked it.  correction made!

Comment: I only want to return 1 propertyforrent.ownerno with this query

Comment: You need to use outer joins not inner... (+) notation or use a different join syntax (Left, Right Full outer).... to know which is appropriate we need to know which RDBMS this is (mySQL, SQL SERVER oracle Other?)

Comment: it would be in mysql

Comment: Where is  real estate salesperson?  Just show the table structures involved

Comment: Thanks so much for your help xQbert. I made a mistake in the original question and have edited it. There is no salesperson....just a propertyowner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use LEFT JOINs here so that all properties for rent are returned
and only those with a related Viewing.

```
SELECT PFR.ownerno, count(Distinct PFR.PropertyNo) Count_of_Unviewed_Properties
FROM PropertyForRent  PFR
LEFT JOIN viewing V
 on PFR.PropertyNo = V.PropertyNo
WHERE V.propertyno IS NULL
ORDER BY count(Distinct PFR.PropertyNo) Desc
LIMIT 1
```

Then we get a count of the Distinct PFR.PropertyNo where there isn't a related viewing, order by this count desc and limit to 1 result which (unless there are ties) will be the owner with the most properties with no viewings.

Assumptions made:

- No need for clients at all here... you're interested in viewings and properties.
- PropertyForRent has PropertyNo
- PropertyForRent.PropertyNo is the PK on that table. and identifies a unique property for a given owner.
- Viewing.propertyNo is a FK to PropertyforRent.PropertyNo
- you're not concerned about "Ties"

Comment: This makes sense....your commentary below is also accurate so I think you've answered my question.  Thanks a lot.  Is there anyway to give you "props" or anything here? I clicked the check mark beside your answer.

Comment: Viewing.propertno and viewing.clientno are both labeled PK

PFR.propertyno is also labeled PK

Comment: The check is the props on this site and it closes out the question indicating you belive this response addresses  your concerns.  The ^ is additional props while the down ^ is not useful at all and could be harmful..  Yes,  aliases should not match the tables they are aliasing, otherwise, why alias at all?

Comment: That **almost** makes sense.  V.PropertyNo and V.ClientNo to me are not unique enough; as the same client could view a property multiple times...  I liked these 3... Lets revist all of them. ok I'm down to 2 lets take a look at the last 2... ok lets visit this one one more time... (3 visits later, by the same client, the property is sold)  But if you're not interested in capturing repeat visits, then its' fine.

Comment: This assignment has been strange from the beginning as I've been asked to work out the queries in a word doc with no access to the tables so that I can actually see what works.

Are you saying that the table schema and the PKs I described are unusual/not proper?

Comment: They Could/Would be fine provided there's no need to record repeated visits.  lets say Jane visits property 123 3 times.  The way this is laid out, you could only record ONE of those visits because Jane (Client) can only visit a property once (by the key in the viewing table)  Add Date/time to that composite key and it would be fine.  Jane could visit it 1000+ times and we'd be able to record every one of them.  it boils down to requirements.  Do we need to know if a client visited a the same property more than once?  If not, keys are fine.  If you do.  the database will NOT let you.

Comment: Understood, but in this case the point might be moot since we are only interested in properties with NULL visits. So once one property is tagged with v.propertyno IS NULL its case closed, right?

Comment: True, I was just commenting on the over all design.  There may be a flaw, but to your specific and original question, yes once the property is tagged with null due to the LEFT join, case closed.  Because we're simply counting the unique/disttinct properties that an owner hasn't had a viewing for.

Comment: Perfect....thanks so much. Tried to ^ you but I'm new here and wasn't allowed to. Hopefully I can get you back on another occasion. Thanks again!

So the query as it is there now is the correct way to do it right? Or should I use the one you wrote before adding the 2nd select item?

Comment: So the query as it is there now is the correct way to do it right? Or should I use the one you wrote before adding the 2nd select item?

Comment: Both are fine.  The first SPECIFICALLY answers the question, the 2nd provides additional data.  Generally a "name" is insufficient **for me** I want to know how many we've not shown.  If it's 1 and they only have 1 listed Its a big deal.  If its 1 and the owner has 20 listed not such a big deal.  It just depends on the use case for this query/data.